# JavaScript - RGBA array to binary

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary, rgba

Given a byte array, which can contain only values `255` or `0`, representing a black and white image in RGBA, for example: `[255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]`.

How would one convert it to an array of bytes, where each bit represents 1 pixel? array above would be `10111111` -> `[191]`

Comment: How long would this array be? Would looping through it iteratively be too unperformant?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @AlphaHowl Array could be long, but looping is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly simple with bit shifting, like so.

```
const arr = [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255];

let colorMask = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=4) {
    if (arr[i] !== 0) {
        colorMask |= 1 << (i / 4);
    }
}
```

So every four bytes are checked if they're non-zero, if not the position in colorMask is set to one.
Note that `colorMask` will not be representing the expected 191 integer, but 253, since the binary representation of numbers and integers are different.

In case you are in need of the decimal representation you'll have to AND every bit into a string, like so:

```
let rep = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    rep += ((colorMask & (1 << i)) ? 1 : 0);
}

console.log(parseInt(rep, 2), rep);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've said looping is no problem, I have used the following approach:

- collect each 4 elements of your original array. This is `[R,G,B,A]`;
- check if it is black, otherwise it is white. Black is `0` and white is `1`.
- Finally convert from base-2 (binary) to base-10 (denary).
- Then alert the user

Check this snippet:

```js
const RGBA_array = [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255];
const byte_array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < RGBA_array.length; i+=4) {
    let color = 1;
    const current_nibble = [RGBA_array[i], RGBA_array[i+1], RGBA_array[i+2], RGBA_array[i+3]];
    if(!current_nibble[3]) color = 0;
    if(!(current_nibble[0]&&current_nibble[1]&&current_nibble[2])) color = 0;
    byte_array.push(color);
};
const base_10_number = parseInt(byte_array.join(""), 2);
document.write("Here is your bitmap as a base-10 number: <b>" + base_10_number + "</b>");
```